# area of quadrilateral in terms of angle

Tags: complex-numbers

> consider the equation $z^4=5(z-1)(z^2-z+1).$ Let roots of the equation be $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3},z_{4}
> .$ If the area of quadrilateral $ABCD$ formed by the points $A(z_{1}),B(z_{2}),C(z_{3}),D(z_{4})$ in the arg-and plane is $2\cos^3\alpha.$ Then $\alpha=$

what i try $$z^4=5(z^3-z^2-z^2+z+z-1)$$

$$z^4=5z^3-10z^2+10z-5$$

$$z^4-5z^3+10z^2-10z+5=0$$

$$z^5-5z^4+10z^3-10z^2+5z-1=-1$$

$$\Longrightarrow (z-1)^5=-1$$

$$(z-1)=(-1)^{\frac{1}{5}}=e^{\frac{i(2n+1)\pi}{5}}$$

for $n=0,1,2,3,4$

How do i solve it Help me

Comment: When I try it I get $2\cos^2\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, but it seems to be $2\cos^\color{blue}{3}\alpha$ for a much more elegant value.  Typo in the problem maybe?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have edited it.Thanks . Please write complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: The roots are rendered by the OP thusly:

$z=1-\exp(i(2k\pi/5)), k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

but this is wrong.  We have instead only

$z=1-\exp(i(2k\pi/5)), k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

The root $z=0$ cotresponding to $k=0$ was introduced extraneously  between the third and fourth lines where there was a multiplication by $z$.

The roots are shown geometrically in the picture below.

[image]

Clearly the four good roots, at the corners of the red trapezoid, are at four vertices of a regular pentagon with center $(1,0)$ and radius $1$ unit from the center to each vertex.

The trapezoid may then be divided into four isosceles triangles whose legs (solid blue lines) measure $1$ unit and whose apex angles are $72°$ (three triangles) or $144°$ (one triangle).  From the fact that each triangle has area equal to half the product of any two sides times the sine of the included angle we infer the total area of the trapezoid:

$A=(3/2)\sin(72°)+(1/2)\sin(144°)$

At this point one may be tempted to render $\sin(144°)=2\sin(72°)\cos(72°)$ with the double angle formula, but because this introduces the cosine function it offers no real progress.  Instead, render the following:

$A=(3/2)\sin(72°)-(1/2)\sin(216°)$

and use the **triple-angle formula**:

$\sin(3\theta)=\sin(2\theta+\theta)=\sin(2\theta)\cos\theta+\cos(2\theta)\sin\theta$

$=2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta+(1-2\sin^2\theta)\sin\theta$

$=2\sin\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)+(1-2\sin^2\theta)\sin\theta$

$=3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$

Plugging this into the area expression given above with $\theta=72°$ and $3\theta=216°$ then gives

$A=(3/2)\sin(72°)-(3/2)\sin(72°)+2\sin^3(72°)$

$=2\sin^3(72°)=2\cos^3(18°)$

from which we read off $\alpha=18°=\pi/10\text{ radians}$.

Answer (score 2):

hint...you can rewrite this equation as $$(z-1)^5=-1$$ excluding $z=0$ so you get four vertices of a regular pentagon.

Comment: Did not understand David Quinn can u explain me in detail.

Comment: Are you having a problem obtaining this equation that I have hinted at, or a problem solving it?

Comment: i mean problem solving @ – David Quinn

Comment: do you know how to find the fifth roots of $-1$?

Comment: yes @David i have edited my answer. Now i am struck

Comment: so draw a picture of the four roots on an Argand diagram and you have a trapezium...

Comment: yes i have a doubt on that part how to find area